# WebApplication using jnlp

Tags: java, web-applications, war, jnlp

I need to use my already running web application using JNLP, Can someone suggest if this is possible?
If yes need some direction to implement this.
I have searched quite a lot on google but could not convince myself.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JNLP is the format of files designed to launch ***desktop applications*** as opposed to web-apps.!

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following link, you will get information about JNLP

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html